# Meteor sending emails with images, image requests are returning with 404

Tags: email, meteor

I'm trying to send an email using an html template via cmather:handlebars-server in Meteor.

I've included email and handlebars into my project. 
I've received the emails, but only the text. None of my css/less or images are being included in the email though.
I believe I am accessing the images correctly, because I can display the html on the browser perfectly fine.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated :D!

UPDATE #1: 
I tried a couple of tests. 
1) deploying my meteor application to meteor.com. The result was the same, images were still not being shown in the email.
2) I tried using a publicly accessible image from imgur, and the image from imgur was displayed.

My images are stored in the /public directory, I assume if my project is deployed on meteor that my images become accessible.. however this may not be the case.

Still open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the images without the `/public` prefix? For example if you have your image stored in `/public/image.jpg` try accesing it directly `/image.jpg`

Comment: yes I have. I can display the html perfectly fine on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer,

You can either include the domain name in the src for your image,
ex.

```
<img src="http://your.domain.com/images/image.png">
```

Or you can use

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl(imgUri)  //for proper image src URLs
```

As for CSS, I come to realize the lack of support for CSS in email clients. So things such as customized fonts and couple HTML5 tags weren't going to work.

Other than that, CSS does work, but I wouldn't trust how it looks in the browser. Instead I would use mailchimp.com